# Limted access over WiFi network

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, router, internet, wifi-driver

In my Wifi network some of the laptops are showing the limited access thats why these laptops are not able to access the internet. If I reset the wireless adapter on device manager at the time its working fine after some time again it repeats the problem, Can any one suggest me right solution to this problem.

Comment: [12 Tips for Troubleshooting Your Internet Connection](http://www.pcmag.com/slideshow/story/262550/12-tips-for-troubleshooting-your-internet-connection)

Comment: [How to Fix Your Wi-Fi Network: 7 Tips](http://www.pcworld.com/article/260524/how_to_fix_your_wi_fi_network_7_tips.html)

Comment: Thanks Mr.DavidPostill, But I tried above both methods but its not working

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I got it.

Change the Wi-Fi Channel on the Router
Most Wi-Fi routers and devices use the 2.4GHz radio band, which has 11 channels in the United States. Unfortunately, only 3 of the 11 channels can run simultaneously without overlapping or interfering with each other: channels 1, 6, and 11. Worse, many routers are set to broadcast on channel 6 by default. Consequently, interference from other routers in the vicinity is a common source of connectivity problems, especially in densely populated areas such as apartment complexes and shopping centers. Other radios that use the 2.4GHz band--for example, baby monitors and cordless phones--and other electrical devices (such as microwave ovens) can interfere with Wi-Fi signals, too.

To see if other wireless routers might be interfering, take a look at the list of nearby wireless networks. If you're using Windows, click the network icon in the lower right corner. If you see other network names, especially those with more than one bar of signal, they could be interfering with your signal.

You can try to dodge interference by changing your router to another channel. You can blindly choose a channel (going with 1 or 11 is probably your best bet) or you can make a better-educated selection by checking to see which channels nearby networks are using so you can use a different channel. You can check with a free program like InSSIDer or Vistumbler, or use the Web-based Meraki WiFi Stumbler. If you don't have access to one of these applications on your laptop, you can use a free app like Wifi Analyzer (on Android devices) or Wi-Fi Finder (on Apple iOS devices) on your smartphone or tablet to scan for Wi-Fi networks.

Once you've decided on a channel to switch to, you'll need to log in to your router's control panel and change the channel. To access the router's Web-based control panel, open a new window in your browser while you're connected to your router's wireless network and then type in its IP address (most commonly 192.168.1.1 or 192.168.0.1).

I changed the standard channel in the router website from channel 6-2.462GHz to 11-2.462GHz now its working fine.